# How to write an SQL Select for XML including Union logic?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union, for-xml

I have the following statement to get both dates into @xmlData

```
declare @xmlData OUTOUT

SET @xmlData = (SELECT @FileDate AS [FileDate] UNION SELECT @satDate AS [FileDate] FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS)
```

Then I will insert it into the table:

```
DECLARE @ListOfDates TABLE (FileDate varchar(50))

        INSERT @ListOfDates (FileDate)
        SELECT Tbl.Col.value('FileDate[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
        FROM @xmlData.nodes('//row') Tbl(Col)
```

When executing my `select` logic, I'm getting an error saying:

> The FOR XML and FOR JSON clauses are invalid in views, inline
>   functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set
>   operator.  To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator
>   using derived table or common table expression or view and apply FOR
>   XML or FOR JSON on top of it.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you're using XML at all here.  But the error is telling you to push down that query into a derived table (subquery) or CTE, like this:

```
declare @xmlData xml
declare @filedate date = getdate()
declare @satdate date = '20140101'

SET @xmlData = (

select * from 
( SELECT @FileDate AS [FileDate] UNION ALL SELECT @satDate AS [FileDate] ) d
FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS, type

)

select @xmlData
```